# How can I separate the elements of an Array and save them into an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, arraylist, bufferedreader

I'm new to Java and I want to read a CSV file into an `ArrayList`.
I'm only interested in the names in the file. Each name group is a `String[]` and inside each array there is maybe one element (name middle names surname) or multiple elements.
I would like to separate the names into `firstName`s and `lastName`s under the assumption the last part of the element is the surname everything else is first name.

This is my code so far:

```java
public class Author {
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    public Author(String name, String surname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return '{' + "name=" + name +
                ", surname=" + surname +
                '}';
    }

    public void listAllNames(){
        String path = "C:\\Users\\ahmex\\Desktop\\publications.shortened.csv";
        String currentLine = "";
        ArrayList<String []> authorNames = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
            while ((currentLine = fileReader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] line = currentLine.split(";");
                String [] authors = (line[1].split(","));
                Collections.addAll(authorNames, authors);
            }
            authorNames.remove(0);
            System.out.println("The list of the Author's names is: ");
            for (String [] authorGroups : authorNames){
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(authorGroups));
            }
            System.out.println("The number of authors on the list is: " + authorNames.size());
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

output: 

The list of the Author's names is: 
[Christian Janze,  Marten Risius]
[Kenan Xiao Auburn University,  Ashish Gupta,  Wenting Jiang,  Xiao Qin]
[Kyuhan Lee,  Sudha Ram]
[Xiaohui Zhang,  Qianzhou Du,  Zhongju Zhang]
[Piyush Vyas,  Jun Liu,  Omar El-Gayar]
[Alex Olivieri,  Shaban Shabani,  Maria Sokhn,  Philippe CudrÃ©-Mauroux]
[Kelvin King-Kizito]
[Samuel KieÃŸling,  Kathrin Figl,  Ulrich Remus]
```

I haven't tried much, since I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: [Edit] your question and post sample data from the CSV file.

Comment: I did thank you for your note.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the separation to be done within the string arrays themselves, this should do the trick:

```
ArrayList<String[]> authorGroupsWithSeparatedNames = authorGroups.stream().map((strArr) -> {
      String[] newStrArr = new String[strArr.length * 2];
      for (int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
          int lastIndexOfWhitespace = strArr[i].lastIndexOf(" ");
          newStrArr[i * 2] = strArr[i].substring(0, lastIndexOfWhitespace);
          newStrArr[i * 2 + 1] = strArr[i].substring(lastIndexOfWhitespace + 1);
      }
      return newStrArr;
    }).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

For the output that you showed, authorGroupsWithSeparatedNames would contain the following:

```
[Christian, Janze, Marten, Risius]
[Kenan Xiao Auburn, University, Ashish, Gupta, Wenting, Jiang, Xiao, Qin]
[KKyuhan, Lee, Sudha, Ram]
[Xiaohui, Zhang, Qianzhou, Du, Zhongju, Zhang]
[Piyush, Vyas, Jun, Liu, Omar, El-Gayar]
[Alex, Olivieri, Shaban, Shabani, Maria, Sokhn, Philippe, CudrÃ©-Mauroux]
[Kelvin, King-Kizito]
[Samuel, KieÃŸling, Kathrin, Figl, Ulrich, Remus]
```